# dotnet core IdentityServer adding roles

Tags: .net-core, jwt, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

Please accept my apologies in advance. This topic is all over the internet including SO and I have looked at hundred of articles over several days and I cannot seem to make this last hurdle.

I am using out of the box dotnet react project with Identity. (dotnet 5.0). I also added Microsoft login.

The authentication works just fine. I can protect resources with [Authorize] for either login type.

But try as I might, I get a 403 error, every time I add a role; ie [Authorize(Role = "Admin")]

I added some dummy users to try it out and then added some code to add the roles. Here is the code for that:

```
public async Task SetupRoles()
    {
        string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Office" };
        
        foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
        {
            var roleExist = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
            {
                var newRole = new IdentityRole(roleName);
                //await _roleManager.CreateAsync(newRole);
                //await _roleManager.AddClaimAsync(newRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName));       
            }
        }
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("me@me.com");
        if (user != null)
        {
            var result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Office");
            //await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
            //await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Office"));
        }
    }
```

I've left in comments in the code I have tried to add unsuccessfully. This code works perfectly in standard MVC project as I copied it from there !

I added an IProfileService class which is from SO:

```
public class MyProfileService : IProfileService
{
    public MyProfileService()
    { }

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        //get role claims from ClaimsPrincipal 
        var claims = context.Subject.FindAll(JwtClaimTypes.Role);
        
        //add your role claims 
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        // await base.IsActiveAsync(context);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and my Startup.cs in ConfigureServices looks like this:

```
       services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDbContext <OfficeManagerContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => 
                      options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


        services.AddIdentityServer()
          .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
          .AddProfileService<MyProfileService>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt()

            .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
            {
                microsoftOptions.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
                microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();
        ...
```

Here is the token that is being sent in the API call:

```
{
  "nbf": 1627003083,
  "exp": 1627006683,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44340",
  "aud": "OfficeManager.AlphaAPI",
  "client_id": "OfficeManager.Alpha",
  "sub": "*******-b0ac3839766c",
  "auth_time": 1627003080,
  "idp": "local",
  "role": [
    "Office",
    "Admin"
  ],
  "jti": "***",
  "sid": "***",
  "iat": 1627003083,
  "scope": [
    "OfficeManager.AlphaAPI",
    "openid",
    "profile"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

and finally, here is the controller, which is the stock WeatherForecastController

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };
    ....
```

To repeat, if I remove the Roles part of Authorize it works fine. With the Roles, I get a 403 error.

The screen is getting blurry !!! Please help !!!

I have incorporated everything I can find and by all accounts, this should be working, but clearly I am an idiot and missing something.

Thanks

Comment: When you inspect the `User` property inside a controller, do you see the role claims?

Comment: @abdusco - Good question, thank you. I  hadn't checked, but now I have and the claims are there in the User property for the roles. Most infuriating !

Comment: Can you also post your `Startup.Configure` method?

Comment: Startup.Configure is exactly as out of the box. The issue is it needs an IClaimsTransformation. I will write up an answer later.

Comment: You shouldn't need an `IClaimsTransformation` to be able to perform authorization by claims. It should work right out of the box.

Comment: services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(). Seems you customized IdentityUser (ApplicationUser) but not IdentityRole??

Comment: @abdusco - It should work out of the box, but its not. That is the issue. I cannot see any actual answers at this time, so I will have to live with this "hack".

Comment: @GHDevOps - apologies, I am not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: IdentityUser is the default class. You're using ApplicationUser which shows you're customizing the user class but not the roles class. If you do one, you have to do all. Look at your implementation for ApplicationUser. It's probably inheriting from IdentityUser.

Comment: @GHDevOps - Thanks. I will look into it. I did not make any change manually. I did scaffold identity which makes changes I believe so will need to look at that a bit more to see if I can get my head around it.